# All printouts condensed into left half on a Samsung Color Laser printer CLP-365W

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

After installing the Samsung Color Laser Printer **CLP-365W** in **12.04**, the printout is condensed into the **left half** of the A4 page (regardless whether 'fit to page' on or off). This happens both with the automatically recognised Ubuntu driver and the 'Unified Linux driver' from the Samsung website.
(The 300.ppd (as per 'Unified driver' install) or 360.ppd are the closest matches to '365'.)

Any help??

## Test page printout

[image: Printout]

## Test page printout closeup

[image: Printout closeup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with CLP-360 on x86_64 laptop. (On x86 all is OK.)

I fixed it using the following driver on cups:

- Samsung CLP-340 Series (SPL-C) (color, 2-sided printing)

Comment: Can you provide more information? What driver were you using before? Did you select the driver you're commending from Additional Drivers, or did you have to download it manually from somewhere on the Internet?

Comment: Had the same problem, but solved differently, using http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ (samsung drivers packaged as deb *and fixed*). There is additional gain when compared to "standard" CLP-360W installation on older, i386 laptop: now it prints *immediately*, even over WiFi and previously it took more than 30s for PC and printer to communicate.
(I would add a separate answer but the question seems to be closed now.)

Answer (score 4):

I used the same driver that Eliah mentioned with success under Linux Mint 13 (basically Ubuntu 12.04)

First, install the Samsung unified driver package from the[Samsung download center](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/main/supportMain.do)).

Extract the Linux folder and open it within the terminal and run:

```
cd ~/Downloads/Linux/
sudo ./install.sh
```

The installation wizard will now open, it might be necessary to disable LPT support during the installation, since disabling it worked for me.

After completing press `Alt+F2` and open system-config-printer and search for the IP of the printer, select the printer and the faulty driver will install. After completing the installation open the properties of the printer and click `change` next to `Make and Model`, select `Provide PPD File` and navigate to "/opt/Samsung/mfp/share/ppd" and select "CLP-340.ppd". Click `Forward` and use the option `Use the PPD (Postscript Printer Description) as is`
and click `Apply`.

The printer should now be installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the below links and use the troubleshooters. Check if it lists and helps resolve any issues: Open the Printer troubleshooter: http://www.samsungdrivers.net/samsung-clp-365w-driver/

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to add the important steps described in the link on this page in case the link expires/changes

Answer (score 0):

Look here 
http://donkeybridge.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/setup-samsung-laser-printer-clp-365w-under-linux/
i have same problem and print is ok after first link in description

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for 2 months after the buy of my CLP-365W.

The `rkoenig` link is sufficient for Ubuntu 12.04, but not totally for 12.10.

[Here my solution for Ubuntu 12.10](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=10737991#p10737991) (I wrote it :  15/11/2012, at 14:13).

Sorry, it's in French (French guy on French forum), but the commands are in shell language.

Comment: Please add the main steps here in English and keep the link to your post on forum.ubuntu-fr.org.